# android- Taking screenshot of a particular view programmatically does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I want to take screenshot of a layout from another activity. When I take view into Bitmap it shows NullPointerExcenption. Here is my code

```
  View v=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.score_share, null);
    layoutScore.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm= Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    layoutScore.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/scs.jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream= new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: have you mentioned write external storage permission in Manifest.xml

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: Yes I did add permission in Manifest

Comment: What's your target version in manifest file? If it's 23 or greater than you have to add run time permission in marshmallow.

Comment: show your logcat..

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dimiklab.mathgame/com.dimiklab.mathgame.ScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.dimiklab.mathgame.ScoreActivity.screenShot(ScoreActivity.java:169)
                                                                           at com.dimiklab.mathgame.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is getDrawingCache returning null, then just add this lines of code before `v.buildDrawingCache(true);`

```
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
          MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
```

This will prevent that the view has a size of (0,0), and because of that it turns null safe.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the method to capture screenshot.

```
 public Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
       View screenView = view.getRootView();
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
       screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       return bitmap;
 }
```

Store the Bitmap into the SDCard:

```
public void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
    final static String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now Inflate your layout and capture screen shot

```
View view=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.score_share, null);

Bitmap bmp = getScreenShot(view);
```

bmp is the required screenshot then save it to SDcard like

```
store(bmp, "Screenshot.jpg");
```

Don't forget to add Write External Storage permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks to this answer [Capture Screenshot and store to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212385/3338287)

Comment: I want to capture screenshot of another layout not this layout

Comment: @IliasAhmed did you mean that you want to take the screenshot of Activity B layout in Activity A ??

Comment: Yes. B is a layout and A is Activity.

Comment: Have a look at answer now hope it will help :)

Comment: @IliasAhmed added lines to inflate layout capture screenshot and save it to device