# Crop Bitmap 150dp from Bottom of Screen to Top of Screen

Tags: android, bitmap

I am use screen capture, and want to crop bitmap programatically **150dp from bottom of screen**.
(Erase bitmap 150dp from bottom of screen)

How to do that?

This is image explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwhUp.jpg

**Edited**. Full code for take screen shot:

```
public void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {

        String folder_main = "APP_FOLDER";
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/APP_FOLDER/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap source = v1.getDrawingCache();
        int x = 0;
        int y = v1.getHeight() ;
        int width = source.getWidth() - x;
        int height = source.getHeight() - y;
        Bitmap bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height);

        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshotWhatsApp (imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm very confusing.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with this  int height = source.getHeight() - 150;

Comment: are you able to take any part of the screenshot atleast ?

Comment: With that code, cannot make a screen shot.

But done with this code:

// create bitmap screen capture
         View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
         v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
         Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
         v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

Comment: Ok then, after taking complete screenshot also you can crop the particular part which you want. try in that way, i m not sure

Comment: Sorry, I test again with: int y = v1.getHeight() -150 ; But just crop for 150dp from bottom of screen.

I need erase 150dp from screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

Call this method, passing in the outer most ViewGroup that you want a screen shot of:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            150, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

For more you can check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212385/3983054) as well

Comment: Please check my edited full code for take screen shot.
Thanks